# Collections.min returns memory location instead of value

Tags: java

I have a basic class called `Coord` with two Integer fields `x` and `y`. I want to use the `Collections.min` method to find the smallest `x` value. However, java returns a memory location rather than a value. The main method is below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<Coord> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new Coord(10, 12));
    list.add(new Coord(8, 4));
    list.add(new Coord(15, 22));
    list.add(new Coord(9, 11));
    list.add(new Coord(56, 7));
    list.add(new Coord(3, 14));
    list.add(new Coord(23, 7));

      System.out.println(
        Collections.min(list, (a, b) -> a.getX().compareTo(b.getX()))
        );
  }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it! `Collections` methods return `Collections` objects, which means you just need to use the `getX` and `getY` methods on that object.

```
Collections.min(list, (a, b) -> a.getX().compareTo(b.getX())).getX()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're calling `Collections.min` on a collection of `Coord` objects, the value returned is a `Coord`. Call `getX()` on it to get the smallest x value.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
Collections.min(list, (a, b) -> a.getX().compareTo(b.getX()))
```

Into

```
Collections.min(list, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.getX(), b.getX())).getX()
```